# Mongoose Query To Get Data For A Particular Date (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having a problem while querying for a particular date in my database
I need to get the data on a particular date

I'm using `$gte` and `$lt` mongo functions to conditionally query the date

But I'm not able to get data which corresponds to the date which i need
I'm receiving back all the data from that date till today's date
Because of the `$gte`(greater than or equal to) function

I'm not able to find a proper solution for this
I tried to look in stackovflw but still couldn't find it

Can someone help me!

This is the query using mongoose I'm trying to get the data only for that particular day

`Attendance.find({teacherID:req.body.id,subject:req.body.subject,grade:req.body.grade , section:req.body.section,date:{"$gte": new Date(req.body.date)}}`

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information. What command are you trying to write? What does your data look like? We need to see your code.

Comment: Can you post some code? what have your tried? what's the desired output? How does your query look like?

Comment: This is the query using mongoose I'm trying to get the data only for that particular day

```Attendance.find({teacherID:req.body.id,subject:req.body.subject,grade:req.body.grade , section:req.body.section,date:{"$gte": new Date(req.body.date)}} ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read the documentation about filter by date at [mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html)